# why do i get error of Undefined name even when the variable is defined?

Tags: flutter, dart, null, dart-null-safety

I am getting an undefined name error even when i defined the var in my dart file,
Below is the error image

[image]

Below is my code

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/products.dart';

class ProductDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String title;

  // ProductDetailsScreen(this.title);
  static const routeName = '/product-detail';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?;

    if (productId != null) {
      final loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context)
          .items
          .firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == productId);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

plus when i try to move the return code-block to the if method like this

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../providers/products.dart';

class ProductDetailsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // final String title;

  // ProductDetailsScreen(this.title);
  static const routeName = '/product-detail';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?;

    if (productId != null) {
      final loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context)
          .items
          .firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == productId);

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

it then throws an error "the body might complete normally, causing null to be returned, but the return type, "widget" is a potentially non-nullable type.

Please i need help as it looks like my unfamiliarity with null-safety is giving me lot of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

The **Second Snippet** will not work because you are not handling the return if the `productId` is `null`, so you have to always return something at the `build()` method.

For the **First Snippet**, the problem is that the variable called `loadedProduct` is defined inside the `if condition` block, which is not accessed outside its scope, to solve the problem you can do the following steps:

1. Define the variable `loadedProduct` outside the `if condition` but not as `final`, e.g. var loadedProduct;
2. Inside the `if condition` set the value of the variable, e.g. `loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context) ...`
3. By now, you have solved the problem if the `productId` is not `null`, but what if it is `null`?, then you have to think about the `UI` at this case, you can simply set a default `title` if the `productId` is `null` to better understand the case, e.g. `Text(loadedProduct?.title ?? 'No Product Found')`

**NOTE:**

```
loadedProduct?.title ?? 'No Product Found'
```

is equivalent to the following:

```
loadedProduct != null ? loadedProduct.title : 'No Product Found'
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, i have updated the question with an image of the error

Comment: You're welcome, I have updated the answer with the solution.

Comment: thank you, but in the first snippet, after correction, it is always returning null and don't even load the title of the product at all

Comment: What is the value that is returned as `null`? does it the `productId`? or the `loadedProduct`?

Comment: the code from the build method is this

`@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String?;
    var loadedProduct;

    if (productId != null) {
      loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context)
          .items
          .firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == productId);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loadedProduct?.title ?? 'No'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
`

Comment: What is the error you are getting for now? the `build()` method is now correct.

Comment: I don't get an error, the app runs but when i tap on a product, instead of getting the product title, i get the 'else' value. which i think simply means it's always skipping the if condition right?

Comment: No, it is not skipping the condition, it will always perform the condition but if you are always getting the `else` part then you have to check the values of `productId` and `loadedProduct` if they are getting `null` values, you can just print them out to find if they are `null` or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have your variable defined, but it is not visible in the place where you want to use it.

In your first snippet:

```
 if (productId != null) {
      final loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context)
          .items
          .firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == productId);
    }
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
      ),
    );
```

You created `loadedProduct` but it is only accessible within `{}` brackets of your if statement. It is called `Lexical Scoping`.

In your second snippets, you can see that you try to use `loadedProduct` variable in a proper scope - it doesn't return undefined. Though notice that if `productId` is null and its if block doesn't execute - you tells your widget to build nothing - null, which is not possible. Consider a simple `else` clause to handle it.

```
if (productId != null) {
      final loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context)
          .items
          .firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == productId);

      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(loadedProduct.title),
        ),
      );
    } else { 
      return Container() 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, if i return container, when i try to load the product details it just returns a blank screen because it is always returning null and i have no idea why it only return null and don't even load my product title

Comment: To be honest, I've never used `ModalRoute.of(context)` which seems to be a new problem here. Try to google how to properly use its methods and you should be good to go. 
I've seen questions related to it on SO, like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108384/how-to-read-modalroute-ofcontext-settings-arguments-properly
So you should figure it out smoothly now :)

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if it is the answer to this post question and create a new one with ModalRoute unless you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

`loadedPorduct` is not available outside the `if(productId!=null)`.

Place this variable  out of it, inside the build context.

```dart
late  final loadedProduct ;
  final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as String?;

if (productId != null) {
   loadedProduct = Provider.of<Products>(context)
        .items
        .firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == productId);
  }
```

And use case will be

```
Text(loadedProduct?.title?? "default TextOn null case"),
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it gives me a LateInitializationError - Local 'loadedProduct has not been initialized